# Getting rid of unsupported versions in image asset catalogue

Tags: ios, xcode5, asset-catalog

I'm only supporting iOS 7 for this app but the AppIcon in the asset catalogue shows the iOS5,6 versions which I don't need.

Incidentally, I think it's causing me the following error:

```
[Allocator] Mapping failed %d
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

If you click the images.xcassets, open attributes inspector for AppIcon, you can deselect the versions you don't want i think.

Comment: it didn't fix my malloc issue, but that's for another post I guess! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah, no problem! I'm still new to programming, but if I knew more, I would help.